# Unity error "must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to setup a system where I pickup an object drop it into a zone, and then the object is destroyed.

So far I have:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TriggerZone2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text MyText;
    private int score;
    public bool CompareTag(string Player);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        MyText.text = "";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        MyText.text = "$" + score;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) {
        score = score + 1;

        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works up until I try to destroy the game object. The console keeps saying

> Assets/Scripts/TriggerZone2.cs(11,21): error CS0501: `TriggerZone2.CompareTag(string)' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial.

I've looked up quite a few threads, but I'm still not sure what it wants me to do with it. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is 'other'? As in the identifier; the word 'other' is used in OnTriggerEnter() but I don't see where that value is defined.

Comment: @jhocking Going by [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) I thought that it would delete anything, BUT the things tagged within it. I'm new to C#, and rusty on Unity though.

Comment: Note that their example code defines 'other' as the parameter to the function. You called it 'coll'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is saying there's no CompareTag() method defined. That error points to line 11 in your script; note that CompareTag() is called on that line, but there is no CompareTag() defined in your script.

In this case, I don't think you wanted to write `public bool CompareTag(string Player);` I'm not sure what you're even trying to do there, but it looks unnecessary so just delete that entire line.

Comment: I figured it out. Basically my goal was to have it so that any object with a certain tag would be deleted, and add to the score. Thanks.